# Tkinter canvas zoom + move/pan get mouse position

Tags: python, tkinter

After reading this post:

[Tkinter canvas zoom + move/pan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656176/tkinter-canvas-zoom-move-pan/48137257#48137257)

I wanted to try to get the position of the cursor/pixel, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

For exemple I want that when I zoom in/out and click on the same point of the image, I get the same x,y coordinates on the image:

I have tried to play with `self.imscale`, to bind a mouse click with the `canvasx(evt.x)` function but nothing works!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Advanced zoom example. Like in Google Maps.
# It zooms only a tile, but not the whole image. So the zoomed tile occupies
# constant memory and not crams it with a huge resized image for the large zooms.
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class AutoScrollbar(ttk.Scrollbar):
    ''' A scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.
        Works only if you use the grid geometry manager '''
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.grid_remove()
        else:
            self.grid()
            ttk.Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)

    def pack(self, **kw):
        raise tk.TclError('Cannot use pack with this widget')

    def place(self, **kw):
        raise tk.TclError('Cannot use place with this widget')

class Zoom_Advanced(ttk.Frame):
    ''' Advanced zoom of the image '''
    def __init__(self, mainframe, path):
        ''' Initialize the main Frame '''
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master=mainframe)
        self.master.title('Zoom with mouse wheel')
        # Vertical and horizontal scrollbars for canvas
        vbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical')
        hbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='horizontal')
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        # Create canvas and put image on it
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, highlightthickness=0,
                                xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        self.canvas.update()  # wait till canvas is created
        vbar.configure(command=self.scroll_y)  # bind scrollbars to the canvas
        hbar.configure(command=self.scroll_x)
        # Make the canvas expandable
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Bind events to the Canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.show_image)  # canvas is resized
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.move_from)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',     self.move_to)
        self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.wheel)  # with Windows and MacOS, but not Linux
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-5>',   self.wheel)  # only with Linux, wheel scroll down
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-4>',   self.wheel)  # only with Linux, wheel scroll up
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', self.pix_pos)
        self.image = Image.open(path)  # open image
        self.width, self.height = self.image.size
        self.imscale = 1.0  # scale for the canvaas image
        self.delta = 1.3  # zoom magnitude
        # Put image into container rectangle and use it to set proper coordinates to the image
        self.container = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, width=0)
        # Plot some optional random rectangles for the test purposes
        minsize, maxsize, number = 5, 20, 10
        for n in range(number):
            x0 = random.randint(0, self.width - maxsize)
            y0 = random.randint(0, self.height - maxsize)
            x1 = x0 + random.randint(minsize, maxsize)
            y1 = y0 + random.randint(minsize, maxsize)
            color = ('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue')[random.randint(0, 4)]
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, activefill='black')
        self.show_image()

    def pix_pos(self, evt=None):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(self.container)
        print("x: " + str(bbox[0]) + ", y: " + str(bbox[1]))
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(evt.x)# / self.imscale                                                                                                                                        
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(evt.y)# / self.imscale                                                                                                                                        
        print(str(evt.x) + ", " + str(evt.y))
        print("x: " + str(evt.x - bbox[0]) + "y: " + str(evt.y - bbox[1]))
        print("imgscale:" + str(self.imscale) + " x: " + str(x) + " y: " + str(y))

    def scroll_y(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Scroll canvas vertically and redraw the image '''
        self.canvas.yview(*args, **kwargs)  # scroll vertically
        self.show_image()  # redraw the image

    def scroll_x(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Scroll canvas horizontally and redraw the image '''
        self.canvas.xview(*args, **kwargs)  # scroll horizontally
        self.show_image()  # redraw the image

    def move_from(self, event):
        ''' Remember previous coordinates for scrolling with the mouse '''
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def move_to(self, event):
        ''' Drag (move) canvas to the new position '''
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)
        self.show_image()  # redraw the image

    def wheel(self, event):
        ''' Zoom with mouse wheel '''
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(self.container)  # get image area
        if bbox[0] < x < bbox[2] and bbox[1] < y < bbox[3]: pass  # Ok! Inside the image
        else: return  # zoom only inside image area
        scale = 1.0
        # Respond to Linux (event.num) or Windows (event.delta) wheel event
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:  # scroll down
            i = min(self.width, self.height)
            if int(i * self.imscale) < 30: return  # image is less than 30 pixels
            self.imscale /= self.delta
            scale        /= self.delta
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:  # scroll up
            i = min(self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())
            if i < self.imscale: return  # 1 pixel is bigger than the visible area
            self.imscale *= self.delta
            scale        *= self.delta
        self.canvas.scale('all', x, y, scale, scale)  # rescale all canvas objects
        self.show_image()

    def show_image(self, event=None):
        ''' Show image on the Canvas '''
        bbox1 = self.canvas.bbox(self.container)  # get image area
        # Remove 1 pixel shift at the sides of the bbox1
        bbox1 = (bbox1[0] + 1, bbox1[1] + 1, bbox1[2] - 1, bbox1[3] - 1)
        bbox2 = (self.canvas.canvasx(0),  # get visible area of the canvas
                 self.canvas.canvasy(0),
                 self.canvas.canvasx(self.canvas.winfo_width()),
                 self.canvas.canvasy(self.canvas.winfo_height()))
        bbox = [min(bbox1[0], bbox2[0]), min(bbox1[1], bbox2[1]),  # get scroll region box
                max(bbox1[2], bbox2[2]), max(bbox1[3], bbox2[3])]
        if bbox[0] == bbox2[0] and bbox[2] == bbox2[2]:  # whole image in the visible area
            bbox[0] = bbox1[0]
            bbox[2] = bbox1[2]
        if bbox[1] == bbox2[1] and bbox[3] == bbox2[3]:  # whole image in the visible area
            bbox[1] = bbox1[1]
            bbox[3] = bbox1[3]
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=bbox)  # set scroll region
        x1 = max(bbox2[0] - bbox1[0], 0)  # get coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) of the image tile
        y1 = max(bbox2[1] - bbox1[1], 0)
        x2 = min(bbox2[2], bbox1[2]) - bbox1[0]
        y2 = min(bbox2[3], bbox1[3]) - bbox1[1]
        if int(x2 - x1) > 0 and int(y2 - y1) > 0:  # show image if it in the visible area
            x = min(int(x2 / self.imscale), self.width)   # sometimes it is larger on 1 pixel...
            y = min(int(y2 / self.imscale), self.height)  # ...and sometimes not
            image = self.image.crop((int(x1 / self.imscale), int(y1 / self.imscale), x, y))
            imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((int(x2 - x1), int(y2 - y1))))
            imageid = self.canvas.create_image(max(bbox2[0], bbox1[0]), max(bbox2[1], bbox1[1]),
                                               anchor='nw', image=imagetk)
            self.canvas.lower(imageid)  # set image into background
            self.canvas.imagetk = imagetk  # keep an extra reference to prevent garbage-collection

path = 'doge.jpg'  # place path to your image here
root = tk.Tk()
app = Zoom_Advanced(root, path=path)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question. Your description is too vague for us to be able to help.

Comment: @BryanOakley do you have a solution?