# Python3.x tkinter: how get coordinates position after zooming and/or padding respect to the original image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` to display an image, pad or zoom it and finally get position of a pixel respect to the original image.

In order to zoom and pad the image I have used the class provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137257/6837288). Both zooming and padding work perfetcly, but I'm not able to get the correct x, y. This is the part of the code useful to understand the zoom/pad:

```
imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((int(x2 - x1), int(y2 - y1)), self.__filter))
imageid = self.canvas.create_image(max(box_canvas[0], box_img_int[0]),
                           max(box_canvas[1], box_img_int[1]),
                           anchor='nw', image=imagetk)
self.canvas.lower(imageid)
```

Among the methods, I would like to add a new method that has been called by:

```
canvas1.canvas.bind("<Button 3>", canvas1.getpoints)
```

whit which I would like to compute the coordinate respect to the original image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read up on [`bbox(item=None)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) and [`coords(item, *coords)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method)