# python- saving image pyramid list to local file to reduce tkinter app startup time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building an app which uses amazing code created by user "FooBar167" used to zoom large images (original post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137257).
Ia m using this code to display very large image. Because of that my app startup time is very long. I tracked down the command that takes the most time:

```
        self.__pyramid.append(self.__pyramid[-1].resize((int(w), int(h)), self.__filter))
```

It is creation of image pyramid and resizing its tiles what takes the most time.
Because my app will use always the same image, there is no need to perform this operation on each and every startup.
Ideal way would be to save the result of this operation to local file so it can be used on next startup. My question is how to save this kind of variable to local file? there are a lot of tutorials on the web how to save "ordinary" variable to file, but not such complicated list of image objects.
Any advice appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would certainly be possible to write a little script to create a series of smaller-sized images from your original and save them as PNGs.  Then, you can just load the series of files instead of resizing.  Whether that's faster or not is a matter for experimentation.